# Performance problem with pixel-by-pixel image processing (Pillow)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I use this approach to convert an ordinary picture into ascii art. But processing even small images on not strong processors just kills them. Is it possible to optimize this? I tried to make something with numpy but I didn't get anywhere. Any help on optimization would be appreciated, thanks. Here is my failed attempt(

Algorithm taken from here: https://github.com/Akascape/Ascify-Art

My code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import math

def make_magic_old(photo, chars="01", char_size=15, char_width=10, char_height=18, scale=0.09):
    # Rounding scale
    scaleFactor = round(scale, 3)
    # Calculate the length of the character list
    charLength = len(list(chars))
    # Calculate the interval for converting a pixel value into a character
    interval = charLength / 256
    # Convert the image to RGB
    photo = photo.convert("RGB")
    # Load font
    fnt = ImageFont.truetype("assets/fonts/FiraCode-Bold.ttf", char_size)
    # Get size of the image
    width, height = photo.size
    # Scaling the image
    photo = photo.resize((int(scaleFactor * width), int(scaleFactor * height * (char_width / char_height))), Image.Resampling.NEAREST)
    # Getting the sizes in a new way after scaling
    width, height = photo.size
    # Load pixels
    pix = photo.load()
    # Create a new image to display the result
    outputImage = Image.new("RGB", (char_width * width, char_height * height), color="black")
    # Create a drawing tool
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(outputImage)
    # Replace pixes to text
    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            r, g, b = pix[j, i]
            # Calculate the average color value
            h = int(r / 3 + g / 3 + b / 3)
            # Convert pixel colors
            pix[j, i] = (h, h, h)
            # Display a symbol instead of a pixel
            draw.text((j * char_width, i * char_height), chars[math.floor(h * interval)], font=fnt, fill=(r, g, b))

    return outputImage

def main():
    photo = Image.open("test.png")
    result_photo = make_magic(photo)
    result_photo.save("result.jpg")
    print("Done!")
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Attempt to optimize with numpy:

```
import numpy as np

def make_magic(photo, chars="01", char_size=15, char_width=10, char_height=18, scale=0.09):
    # Rounding scale
    scaleFactor = round(scale, 3)
    # Calculate the length of the character list
    charLength = len(chars)
    # Convert the image to RGB and then to numpy array
    photo = np.array(photo.convert("RGB"))
    # Load font
    fnt = ImageFont.truetype("assets/fonts/FiraCode-Bold.ttf", char_size)
    # Get size of the image
    height, width, _ = photo.shape
    # Scaling the image
    photo = np.array(Image.fromarray(photo).resize((int(scaleFactor * width), int(scaleFactor * height * (char_width / char_height))), Image.NEAREST))
    # Getting the sizes in a new way after scaling
    height, width, _ = photo.shape
    # Convert the image to grayscale
    grayscale_photo = np.mean(photo, axis=2).astype(np.uint8)
    # Calculate indices for character selection
    indices = (grayscale_photo * (charLength / 256)).astype(int)
    # Create a new image to display the result
    outputImage = Image.new("RGB", (char_width * width, char_height * height), color="black")
    # Create a drawing tool
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(outputImage)
    # Create character array
    char_array = np.array(list(chars))
    # Replace pixels with text
    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            draw.text((j * char_width, i * char_height), char_array[indices[i, j]], font=fnt, fill=tuple(photo[i, j]))
    return outputImage
```

Img before:
[image: Img before]

Img after:
[image: Img after]

Comment: Kindly add *"before"* and *"after"* images so we can see what it is supposed to do. Also, where does the algorithm come from (do you have a link) and where is it described?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I edited the post from where I got the algorithm, and also added before and after images.

Comment: What kind of performance are you hoping to get? I tested this and it ran in 31 ms on my machine, not counting the disk IO, which is pretty good already. Are you attempting to process many images or especially large images? The slowest parts are disk IO, image resize and the draw command in the loop, the rest runs borderline instantly, and neither of those can be effectively optimized short of rewriting the draw command, which maybe could be improved with a `numpy` + `numba` approach, but the improvement compared to the investment will be extremely small.

Comment: @BitsAreNumbersToo, Thanks for the feedback, I use Ampere processors from Oracle, they are quite weak, and processing takes about 2-5 seconds depending on the image, also if you play with the Scale parameter, for example, set it to 0.2, then the result can reach up to a minute(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original algorithm really isn't that bad, so alot of speedup is going to be pretty challenging. For very small image outputs, the solution presented here is about 2x slower, and for very large outputs, this solution is about 30x faster.

Testing on my machine even with an SSD, `PIL.Image.open` and `PIL.Image.save` were very impactful on the runtime, especially on the smaller files. That is unavoidable, so I focused on the image creation component.

The basic concept of this solution is to pre-generate all of the letters, then tile them into overall image taking advantage of `numpy` and `numba` 's amazing synergy for basic matrix operations like that.

The font step is not particularly amenable to being `numba` compiled, so that is left in python-land. If you needed to process many files, you could call the sub function in a loop, and spare the repeated font step.

Here is the solution I came up with, with a little extra testing boilerplate code:

```
import time

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import math
import numba
import numpy as np

def make_magic_old(photo, chars="01", char_size=15, char_width=10, char_height=18, scale=0.09):
    # Rounding scale
    scaleFactor = round(scale, 3)
    # Calculate the length of the character list
    charLength = len(list(chars))
    # Calculate the interval for converting a pixel value into a character
    interval = charLength / 256
    # Convert the image to RGB
    photo = photo.convert("RGB")
    # Load font
    fnt = ImageFont.truetype("font.ttf", char_size)
    # Get size of the image
    width, height = photo.size
    # Scaling the image
    photo = photo.resize((int(scaleFactor * width), int(scaleFactor * height * (char_width / char_height))),
                         Image.Resampling.NEAREST)
    # Getting the sizes in a new way after scaling
    width, height = photo.size
    # Load pixels
    pix = photo.load()
    # Create a new image to display the result
    outputImage = Image.new("RGB", (char_width * width, char_height * height), color="black")
    # Create a drawing tool
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(outputImage)
    # Replace pixes to text
    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            r, g, b = pix[j, i]
            # Calculate the average color value
            h = int(r / 3 + g / 3 + b / 3)
            # Convert pixel colors
            pix[j, i] = (h, h, h)
            # Display a symbol instead of a pixel
            draw.text((j * char_width, i * char_height), chars[math.floor(h * interval)], font=fnt, fill=(r, g, b))

    return outputImage


def make_magic(photo, chars="01", char_size=15, char_width=10, char_height=18, scale=0.09):
    # Convert the image to RGB
    photo = photo.convert("RGB")
    # Load font
    fnt = ImageFont.truetype("font.ttf", char_size)
    # Make character masks to tile into output image
    char_masks = np.empty((len(chars), char_height, char_width, 3), np.ubyte)
    for i, char in enumerate(chars):
        tim = Image.new('RGB', (char_width, char_height), color='black')
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(tim)
        draw.text((0, 0), char, font=fnt, fill=(255, 255, 255))
        char_masks[i, :] = np.array(tim)
    # Call the numpy + numba optimized function
    new_img_array = _make_magic_sub(np.array(photo), char_masks, char_width, char_height, scale)
    return Image.fromarray(new_img_array, 'RGB')


@numba.njit(cache=True, parallel=True)
def _make_magic_sub(photo, char_masks, char_width, char_height, scale):
    interval = 1 / char_masks.shape[0]
    new_size = (int(photo.shape[0] * scale * char_width / char_height), int(photo.shape[1] * scale), 3)
    outimage = np.empty((new_size[0] * char_height, new_size[1] * char_width, 3), np.ubyte)

    for i in numba.prange(new_size[0]):
        for j in range(new_size[1]):
            rgb = photo[int(i / new_size[0] * photo.shape[0]), int(j / new_size[1] * photo.shape[1])] / 255
            char_num = int(np.floor(np.sum(rgb) / 3 / interval))
            outimage[i * char_height: (i + 1) * char_height, j * char_width: (j + 1) * char_width, :] = char_masks[char_num] * rgb

    return outimage

def _gt(s=0.0):
    return time.perf_counter() - s

def main():
    photo = Image.open("test.png")
    N = 10
    for scale in [0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0]:
        for fun in [make_magic_old, make_magic]:
            fun(photo)  # To skip any caching / compilation times
            s = _gt()
            for i in range(N):
                result_photo = fun(photo, scale=scale)
            e = _gt(s)
            print(f'{fun.__name__:16}{scale:4.2f}  : {e / N * 1000:7.1f} ms')
        print()

    res_old = make_magic_old(photo, scale=0.2)
    res_new = make_magic(photo, scale=0.2)
    res_old.save('result_old.png')
    res_new.save('result_new.png')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Which gives the following results:

```
make_magic_old  0.01  :     2.2 ms
make_magic      0.01  :     4.7 ms

make_magic_old  0.05  :    18.6 ms
make_magic      0.05  :     5.1 ms

make_magic_old  0.10  :    65.9 ms
make_magic      0.10  :     6.9 ms

make_magic_old  0.20  :   256.1 ms
make_magic      0.20  :    13.1 ms

make_magic_old  0.50  :  1601.3 ms
make_magic      0.50  :    58.7 ms

make_magic_old  1.00  :  6379.3 ms
make_magic      1.00  :   194.2 ms
```

Tested on Windows 10, i9-10900K, Python 3.11.4

Your results may vary significantly, I'm running on a far from "not strong processor", but I think this will help you on most multithreaded processors, and you can see that we got about a 32x speed up on the largest output image.

Output from the new code:
[image: new output]

And output from the old code for comparison:
[image: old output]

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Cool - well done! I was thinking about exactly this approach and reckoning it could help, but didn't feel like coding it up, so you saved me a job.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Ahh, thank you for the call out! I really like these types of problems, always so fun. Feel free to suggest any improvements or optimizations if you notice any

Comment: @MarkSetchell that would really help a lot! Thank you <3

Comment: @BitsAreNumbersToo One question that came up is why we didn't replace the second prange in the code: for i in numba.prange(new_size[0]): and for j in range(new_size[1]):

Comment: @Lumo Great question, you usually don't need to, especially if the outter loop has more iterations than your number of available execution threads as you already get good cpu utilization. Because you would then have the overhead of trying to multithread the inner loop as well, it can end up being slower, especially if the inner loop is very fast. Its hard to guess when that will happen, so I just test it to find out. Try it with both multithreaded, and with each one multithreaded separately, and see which is fastest. When I tested, multithreading only the outter was fastest.